# Erro ao passar argumentos em JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Estou tentando fazer uma inserção no MongoDB passando alguns argumentos em JSON:

```
{
    "name": "TESTE", 
    "category": "B", 
    "service": "Novo processo", 
    "description": "Novo Teste", 
    "active": false,
    "classmodels": [
        {"id": "5bbe37ef8eb26d0025624fcd", "amount": 10},
        {"id": "5bbe37ef8eb26d0025624fcd", "amount": 14}
    ]
}
```

Está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

Também está retornando o status code como 500(Internal Server Error), mas eu estou conseguindo usar outros endpoints sem problema nenhum.

As funções no NodeJS que eu estou usando são essas:

Primeira a ser chamada.

```
addStandardClassTemplate: function(req, res) {
        let name = req.body.name;
        let category = req.body.category;
        let service = req.body.service;
        let description = req.body.description;
        let active = req.body.active;
        let classmodels = req.body.classmodels;
        console.log('Entrou no método de Adicionar Template de Aula Padrão');
        classtemplatesMethods.add.addStandard(name, category, service, description, active, classmodels)
            .then((result) => {
                res.status(200).send(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                res.status(404).send(error);
            });
    },
```

Segunda a ser chamada.

```
addStandard: function(name, category, service, description, active, classmodels) {
        classmodels.forEach((item, index) => classmodels[index] = ObjectId(item));

        let NewValues = {
            name: name,
            category: category,
            service: service,
            description: description,
            active: active,
            classmodels: classmodels,
        };
        console.log('QUERY Adicionar Template de Aula Padrão');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            mongoMethods.add.insert(targetcollection, NewValues)
                .then((result) => resolve(result))
                .catch((error) => reject(error));
        });
    },
```

Comment: Olá Henrique, vi que na sua model você tem essa linha: classmodels.forEach((item, index) => classmodels[index] = ObjectId(item)); é realmente necessário você popular novamente o array classmodels com os mesmos valores?

Comment: Eu estou usando esse forEach para transformar o id que eu passo para ObjectId. Não consegui entender o que você disse sobre estar populando novamente o array.

Comment: Note que neste `classmodels[index]` voce esta reescrevendo todo o registro e não só o `.id`, mesma coisa com o `ObjectId(item)`, deveria ser `ObjectId(item.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Através do bate-bola que rolou nos comentários da pergunta detectamos que faltava apenas um `.id` =)

```
//classmodels.forEach((item, index) => classmodels[index] = ObjectId(item));
classmodels.forEach((item, index) => classmodels[index].id = ObjectId(item.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Henrique, veja essa documentação do MongoDB sobre o ObjectID:
link da documentação oficial: [Documentação Mongo DB](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html)

```js
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
    GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
    Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
    Code = require('mongodb').Code,
    BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
    assert = require('assert');

// Create a new ObjectID
var objectId = new ObjectID();
// Convert the object id to a hex string
var originalHex = objectId.toHexString();
// Create a new ObjectID using the createFromHexString function
var newObjectId = new ObjectID.createFromHexString(originalHex)
// Convert the new ObjectID back into a hex string using the toHexString function
var newHex = newObjectId.toHexString();
// Compare the two hex strings
assert.equal(originalHex, newHex);
```